# Restore Verify Only Loop with Update

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-backups

I'm running a Restore Verify Only loop through a table, but I need it to UPDATE a field in that table if it's successful. Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @Path NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @DatabaseName NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @NSql NVARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @Update NVARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @DB_Text NVARCHAR(50)= 'Backup has been confirmed for'

BEGIN
DECLARE
     @DatabaseId INT = 1,
     @NumberOfDBs INT
SELECT  @NumberOfDBs= COUNT(*) FROM dbo.RestoreVerifyDatabases
WHILE @DatabaseId<=  @NumberOfDBs
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM dbo.RestoreVerifyDatabases WHERE DatabaseId=  @DatabaseId         
    SET  @DatabaseId = @DatabaseId + 1
END


SET @Path = (SELECT LastBackupFileName FROM RestoreVerifyDatabases WHERE DatabaseId = 
@DatabaseId)
SET @DatabaseName = (SELECT DatabaseName FROM RestoreVerifyDatabases WHERE DatabaseId = 
@DatabaseId)

SET @NSql = N'SELECT LastBackupFileName
FROM RestoreVerifyDatabases 
WHERE DatabaseName = @DatabaseName
AND DatabaseId = @DatabaseId'

EXEC sp_executesql @NSql

IF @DatabaseId IS NULL
    BEGIN 
         RAISERROR(N'Verify failed. Backup information for database N''@DatabaseName'' not 
 found.', 16, 1) 
    END

RESTORE VERIFYONLY 
FROM @Path
WITH FILE = @DatabaseId,  checksum

SET @Update= N'UPDATE RestoreVerifyDatabases
SET Confirmed = @DB_Text + @DatabaseName
WHERE DatabaseID = @DatabaseId'

EXEC sp_executesql @Update

END
```

The looping and calling of Restore Verify Only works fine but the UPDATE is not getting called. Please help.

Comment: Am I overlooking something? Your first WHILE loop does a SELECT, then increases `databaseID`. This means your `databaseid` is increasing within that loop until you reach the maximum one. And then it leaves the loop with the static value of the latest ID and runs a bunch of code. 

Shouldn't you wait increasing the `databaseID` and having the END until you've processed all the other code? Or is it the poor indentation that's making it look differently?

Comment: Schmitz-Thanks for your quick answer. I might have indented incorrectly but I wanted to use the @DatabaseID as a marker to ensure the UPDATE was on the correct record. I was trying to perform 2 succinct operations which is why there is 2 ENDs.

Comment: If you need a cursor, then just use a friggin cursor. Why do you assume ANYTHING about the values that exist for DatabaseID? And you SHOULD be using the SYSNAME datatype for any object name - like database.

Comment: @SMor I caught that too. That might explain why there's a RAISEERROR that wouldn't be necessary if the code only went for existing databaseids.

Comment: @JackW9653 - I believe the primary issue was the loop assigning Ids. I added a number of other comments below which hopefully help you figure out some other ways to simplify your code. Don't fret it too much. You're working with dynamic SQL, which can be extremely tricky to get to work properly. It certainly took me a while, and despite having used it for close to 20 years, I still manage to make mistakes ;)

Comment: Thank you SchmitzIT, I'm reworking the query now using your comments. I'm getting a couple of errors, but I'm sure I can work them out. If not, there's always Stackoverflow!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things wrong with your code as far as I can see. As my comment indicated, you run a loop over the `@databaseID`, and then immediately increase the id with 1 within the loop.

This means your `@databaseId` simply will increase until it reaches the maximum value of the id, and then exits the loop. The rest of your code will then execute once (only for that ID).

That happens here in your code:

```
SELECT  @NumberOfDBs= COUNT(*) FROM dbo.RestoreVerifyDatabases
WHILE @DatabaseId<=  @NumberOfDBs
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM dbo.RestoreVerifyDatabases WHERE DatabaseId=  @DatabaseId         
    SET  @DatabaseId = @DatabaseId + 1
END

-- Bunch of other code
```

So @databaseID goes from 1 to 50 (just a random number) within that loop, then exists with a value of 50. None of the underlying code ever gets to see any value other than 50.

To fix that, the code should look like this:

```
SELECT  @NumberOfDBs= COUNT(*) FROM dbo.RestoreVerifyDatabases
WHILE @DatabaseId<=  @NumberOfDBs
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM dbo.RestoreVerifyDatabases WHERE DatabaseId=  @DatabaseId         

    -- Bunch of other code
    SET  @DatabaseId = @DatabaseId + 1
END
```

This would ensure the "bunch of other code" processes @databaseid = 1, then processes @databaseid = 2, etc. until @databaseid = 50.

You can also remove this line:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.RestoreVerifyDatabases WHERE DatabaseId=  @DatabaseId
```

I suspect you have it for debugging purposes, but it doesn't really do anything.

These lines can be simplified:

```
SET @Path = (SELECT LastBackupFileName FROM RestoreVerifyDatabases WHERE DatabaseId = 
@DatabaseId)
SET @DatabaseName = (SELECT DatabaseName FROM RestoreVerifyDatabases WHERE DatabaseId = 
@DatabaseId)
```

as:

```
    SELECT @Path = LastBackupFileName, @DatabaseName = DatabaseName FROM RestoreVerifyDatabases WHERE DatabaseId = @DatabaseId
```

You also have a RAISEERROR. I suspect that is because you do a count(*), rather than selecting actually existing @databaseids. This works in an ideal scenario, where databases never get deleted. In the reasl world, though, you'd go from databaseid 1 to 5, because 2, 3, and 4 were removed. Your count will still be 50 databases, but you'd miss all databases with ids above the count due to these gaps. You'd be trying to process the databaseid that no longer exists, and miss the ones with an id > 50.

You could instead write your loop to do something like the following:

```
SELECT @DatabaseID = MIN(DatabaseID) FROM dbo.RestoreVerifyDatabases
WHILE @datbaseID IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    -- Do stuff

    SELECT @DatabaseID = MIN(DatabaseID) FROM dbo.RestoreVerifyDatabases WHERE databaseID > @databaseID
END
```

Finally, your dynamic code isn't working. You are adding literal text rather than the value of the parameters. If I print the value of @Update at the end, it shows as:

```
UPDATE RestoreVerifyDatabases
        SET Confirmed = @DB_Text + @DatabaseName
        WHERE DatabaseID = @DatabaseId
```

Your code should be something like:

```
SET @Update= CONCAT('UPDATE RestoreVerifyDatabases SET Confirmed = ''', @DB_Text, ' ',  @DatabaseName, ''' WHERE DatabaseID = ',  @DatabaseId)
```

Which outputs:

```
UPDATE RestoreVerifyDatabases SET Confirmed = 'Backup has been confirmed for Last' WHERE DatabaseID = 2
```